# Io string (Sequence) manipulation/formatting?

Tags: iolanguage

Does Io have built in methods that mirror the `ord()` and `chr()` functions in other languages (namely being able to take an integer and return the ASCII character associated with it, or take a string character and return the ASCII number for that character)?

Is there a `print`/`write` function that allows for formatting of the output? I'm wanting to create ANSI colored output to the command line, and need the means to print an escape character (ASCII character 27) to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `chr()` see [`asCharacter`](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Number/asCharacter) in the [`Number`](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Number) object.

For `ord()` either [`asBinarySignedInteger`](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Sequence/asBinarySignedInteger) or [`asBinaryUnsignedInteger`](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Sequence/asBinaryUnsignedInteger) from the [`Seqence`](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/reference/index.html#/Core/Core/Sequence) object seems to fit the bill.

```
# ord
"@" asBinarySignedInteger println     # => 64

# chr
64 asCharacter println                # => "@"
```